# How do I reinstall wifi firmware in Arch?

Tags: arch-linux, firmware

For a month, I've had no internet because of an rf-kill problem.  I've followed advice here and in the Arch wiki, but no luck.  rf-kill insists that my wifi is hardlocked.

I want to reinstall the wifi firmware cleanly, but I don't know the best way to do this.
How do I do this?

Comment: If `rf-kill` show that wifi is *hardlocked* in the most cases it mean that you switchoff your card either by hard switch or by hot key (for example in Asus notebooks it usually is `Fn+F2` ).
To be sure that is the soft reason try to start with some Live-system and check your connection.

Comment: There's no hardware switch and the hot key doesn't do anything.  That was the first thing I tried.  Like I said, I've been trying this for a month.

Comment: To make the help possible please indicate your hardware more unshadowed. Additionally you can search swithch in BIOS setup. Do your use dualboot with some Windows system?

Comment: Toshiba can have quirky BIOS software. I advice you to try and go into the BIOS
check your settings., particularly try resetting to default.
does ethernet work ok?

Comment: @bloolips I checked the BIOS.  I've tried playing with all the settings there and there has been no change.  I've tried resetting to default and no luck.  Yes, ethernet works.